# 'Could not find a part of the path' error when extracting zip in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, path

I'm trying to extract a zip file to a location and I get the following error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the
>   path 'D:\test\Server\project\test.edb\Article.eod'.'

I'm running VS Studio with Administrator rights. The source file exists and the relative path seem correct on debugging. The actual zip file contains folders and files within folders, I'm not sure if that is the cause to the problem.

```
string zipPath = @".\..\..\assets\project.zip";
string projectPath = @".\..\..\project";
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        String fullPath = Path.Combine(projectPath, entry.FullName);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath));
        }
        entry.ExtractToFile(fullPath, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hit F10 and debug your code. You only create the directory when `entry.Name` is empty, which is most likely never the case.

Comment: @CodeCaster But isn't the logic correct? A directory is created if the current entry is the foldername and not a file and then the files inside it are recursively extracted to it.

Comment: I don't know this API by heart, are you sure a directory in the zip file is represented by an entry? AFAIK, it isn't, so your `if()` will never be executed. Again, step through your code to find out. It also doesn't hurt to call `Directory.CreateDirectory()`, that method itself will do nothing if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered that challenge. Initially, the files in subfolders were not being extracted because the subfolders were not created. Therefore, for each file, I extracted the directory path using `var destDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);` and then proceeded to create the directory and subdirectories using `Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirPath);`. Afterwards I extracted the file to be extracted.

The other thing I found is that the paths I had constructed were in the form: `C:\\OUTPUT\\` whereas `entry.FullName` was returning code in the form `folder/file.zip`. I modified my paths to match those being returned by `entry.FullName` i.e. `C:/OUTPUT/`.

The DirectoryNotFoundException still occurs whenever `entry.ExtractToFile()` is called with an argument that evaluates to a subfolder, but it's more of a warning since the files under the subfolder are still extracted. This is why I ignored the exception altogether.

Here is code I used:

[image]

Comment: I ran into this issue today - I would recommend checking the if entry.Length is greater that zero and only ExtractToFile in that situation..  Will avoid the unnecessary errors

Answer (score -1):

`entry.ExtractToFile` extracts an entry in the zip archive to a file, it will have errors for the directory.

If you would like to extract a zip file, you could just use

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, projectPath);
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netcore-3.0

Comment: ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, projectPath) fails if the file already exists. ExtractToFile(fullPath, true) lets you override